# Can log4j2 able to generate stdout/stderr log file on daily basis?

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, log4j2

As the title mention, I want to generate my **stdout.log** and **stderr.log** files on daily basis by using log4j2 logging configuration. Is there any way to generate it without restarting my Tomcat server? Or it still the same like log4j version 1 that cannot do the task as I mention above?

my sample log4j.properties:

```
og4j.rootLogger = INFO,MANAGER,CONSOLE
log4j.appender.MANAGER=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MANAGER.File=${catalina.base}/logs/manager.
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Append=true
log4j.appender.MANAGER.Encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.MANAGER.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm'.log'
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MANAGER.layout.ConversionPattern = %n %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n

log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File = $(catalina.base)/logs/stdout.log
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Encoding = UTF-8
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern =%n %d [%t] %-5p %c- %m%n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to a stdout.log and stderr.log. Stdout and Stderr are typically handled by the ConsoleAppender and aren't routed to a file at all. If you want your output in a file they you would use some sort of file appender. Log events are never directed specifically to stdout or stderr by the application, only the configuration, so I am somewhat confused by your question.

Log4j 1 has a RollingFileAppender that will let you roll over the files every day, so I am not really sure why you are saying it cannot perform the task. Log4j 2 also has a RollingFileAppender, although it is a bit different, and it can also roll over the files every day.

Are you really wanting to know how to get Tomcat to direct its log events to Log4j 2?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I know that RollingFileAppender can roll over my files daily. But what i want is exactly logs that handled by ConsoleAppender and able to roll on daily basis. It is possible to do it? Or is there other logging can do such task? Please help.

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make any sense. Just replace the Console appender with a rolling file appender, or add a rolling file appender in addition to the console appender.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Can you give an example on how to add rolling file appender in addition to the console appender? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had edit my question by showing my log4jj.properties. As you can see my log4j.appender.Manager able rotate every minutes by setting up the DatePattern to the format '.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm'  because i had use DailyRollingFileAppender. What my objective is to rotate the second part, which is my CONSOLE, I want to rotate it like how the MANAGER did but using ConsoleAppender. May i know how to add two appender together to make things work? Thanks.

Comment: Roll the console where? The console writes to stdout, which often is your terminal screen. In the case of an application like Tomcat it takes ownership of stdout and routes it to a file, but the logging system has no idea that that is going on.  If you want your Tomcat logs to roll over then I would suggest doing a search on how to do that as that is a common thing to do.

Comment: I think i get what you mean after all. Thanks for your kind response.